# Shared Power BI Datasources on server

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

our current SSRS setup has Shared Datasources (to SQL server/db) so many reports can use them.

Is such a setup possible in PowerBI?

So A developer can login/use this shared datasource to build their report/db, then publish on the server, and when user executes the report, it uses a service account on that shared datasource?

Comment: a 5 second search uncovered this... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-share

Comment: Thank you Alan Schofield. I already performed this search, and like most Microsoft documentation (which barely touches the surface), I needed more specific information.  Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can produce a dataset in PowerQuery and optionally build out visuals. Once deployed to PowerBI Service you can connect to the dataset from many other PowerBI reports (PBIX files). You also have the option of re-using PowerBI data flows.

[image]

Control access using Manage Permissions

[image]

Comment: We have on-premise PowerBI Installation.  Will this work for us? When I go to PowerBI App, and click on Datasets, I just get a blank screen.

Comment: Ah, I dont think this is implemented in on-prem.